# what is the format of data when retrieved (hindi or english font data ) from postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jasper-reports

In postgres data is saving in hindi font. When retrieving the data from java code I need to know which format(Unicode or anything other than that) data is retrieving.Please help..

Answer (score 0):

It is UTF-8 Format.
I was trying to print in pdf was using kruti dev font. It was not printing hindi font and was showing blank.

Used Arial Unicode MS font. In drop down of jasper text font it was missing just copy pasted the name and it worked.